# Why Handoff is not working after network reset? (iOS/iPadOS 13.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, network, continuity

I reset Network settings on my iPhone XS and on my iPad Pro (2018) two days ago. Since then, Handoff works only from iPhone to Mac (10.14.6) but it doesn’t in the other direction.

I have already turned off every option suggested by support and restarted devices before turning them back on.

What can I do now? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, resetting the network settings clears the network connection so that the keys Apple generates / matches to know which device is yours may be expired or need to be renewed / re-keyed.

Connect to WiFi on all devices and make sure iCloud is working would be my first triage step here.